# Enabling fast cgi on php 5.3.29

Tags: php, fastcgi

How to enable FastCGI while php 5.3.29 configure?
I tried to .configure PHP 5.3.29 installation with

--enable-fastcgi

but looks like this option is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php

> As of PHP 5.3.0 this argument no longer exists and is enabled by --enable-cgi instead.

Comment: You might consider Googling it next time you suspect such a thing.